Prototype assignment within a factory in order to achieve private field handling versus constructor and private state without prototypal methods
I know there have been a lot of questions about module patterns, prototypical inheritance, ES6 classes, etc with excellent answers. This is not about discussing different patterns or the bad sides of ES6 classes.
My question, to which I couldn't find a clear answer in the existing questions, is about the difference and pros and cons of two specific approaches.
I like the flexibility that comes with the module pattern and I fully understand the pitfalls, limitations and downsides of relying on the prototype chain (whether or not using the class keyword or traditional function with prototype). However, I want (and sometimes need) the objects that I create to be "identifiable" through instanceof.
I'm aware of two approaches that combine module pattern (and ability to do object composition) while tying the object's prototype to the function that created it.
Method 1: Like module pattern, but we manually set the prototype of the object returned
function Bar() {
  let privateVar = 1;
  const someMethod = () => {
    // do something
  };

  return Object.setPrototypeOf({ someMethod }, Bar.prototype);
}
const b = new Bar() // can omit new as well
console.log(b, b instanceof Bar); // gets a nice "Bar" name in the console + instanceof true

Method 2: Wrapper class and assigning all methods in the constructor
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    let privateVar = 1
    this.someMethod = () => {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
const f = new Foo() // must call with new
console.log(f, f instanceof Foo); // same as Method 1

Question
Are there any downsides to either approach, is one clearly better or worse. Or are they both bad in the sense that they are violating the expectation that the class or constructor function can be "extended" and one would expect to find the properties/methods on the prototype?

This could get closed for being opinion based... I think the function pattern is awkward and outdated. The class pattern makes more sense to me, especially compared to other languages. I would not assign the variable and the method in the constructor, the local variable will cease to exist. I would list the method under/after the constructor, using someMethod = () => { ... }.

@PeterB Thanks for your input. Can you explain what you mean by "the local variable will cease to exist"? It's meant to be a private variable that's used by someMethod and other methods. That's why they're assigned in the constructor, so they can make use of the private variable in the closure. Apologies if this was not clear in my example.

I never thought about it that way but that would work. As for other aspects, tools like VS Code might be able to do code completion for a class defined like I described, but not for a class written in your style.

I don't see any module pattern here?

@Bergi Can you elaborate on what you understand to be a module pattern? Perhaps we're applying different meanings to it. I'm basing my definition on this: https://dev.to/bytebodger/replacing-javascript-classes-with-the-module-design-pattern-48bl

@AaylaSecura That article is wrong: "It's really just a function - that returns an object." - this is not the module pattern, this is what is known as a factory function. The module pattern creates a module object, typically via an IIFE, also known as the "revealing module pattern". See e.g. Addy Osmani JavaScript Design Patterns.

I see, perhaps I should update my title to say "factory function"? Thanks for clarifying.


Are they both bad in the sense that they are violating the expectation that the class or constructor function can be "extended"?

No. Only your first snippet does not support subclassing, because it does hard-code the prototype to Bar.prototype. The usual way to write this would be to still just use this in the constructor:
function Bar() {
  let privateVar = 1;
  this.someMethod = () => {
    // do something
  };
}

If you want to handle callers forgetting the new keyword, there's various approaches to fix this:
function Bar() {
  if (!(new.target && this instanceof Bar)) throw new Error('Invalid call');
  let privateVar = 1;
  this.someMethod = () => {
    // do something
  };
}
function Bar() {
  let privateVar = 1;
  const someMethod = () => {
    // do something
  };
  if (new.target) {
    this.someMethod = someMethod;
  } else {
    return { __proto__: Bar.prototype, someMethod };
  }
}
function Bar() {
  const self = new.target ? this : { __proto__: Bar.prototype };
  let privateVar = 1;
  self.someMethod = () => {
    // do something
  };
  return self;
}


Are they both bad in the sense that one would expect to find the properties/methods on the prototype?

Yes, but no actually this is no longer generally expected. There is a lot of code out there creating function-valued own properties on instances (using ES5 style, ES6 class syntax or ES2022 class fields), whether that's for creating bound methods or closures over private state or something else.
It helps if you point this out in your documentation, together with the expectations on contracts that a subclass should fulfill.

Thank you for your input :) I'll leave this open for a few more days to allow for other answers before accepting.
